# Prototype JS framework for Ajax request

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, ajax-request

How can I implement Prototype JS framework on my project. I have this simple form it will replace city and state by user's zip code input. I need make this work with Ajax Prototype call and I am not getting the result. This is my js and php and html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- popcornA.html 
     This describes popcorn sales form page which uses
     Ajax and the zip code to fill in the city and state
     of the customer's address
     -->
<html lang = "en">
  <head> <title> Popcorn Sales Form (Ajax) </title>
    <style type = "text/css">
      img {position: absolute; left: 400px;  top: 50px;}
    </style>
      
    <script type = "text/JavaScript" src = "prototype.js" src = "popcornA.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/JavaScript" src = "popcornA.js"></script>
      
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> Welcome to Millenium Gynmastics Booster Club Popcorn 
         Sales 
    </h2>

    <form action = "">

<!-- A borderless table of text widgets for name and address -->

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> Buyer's Name: </td>  
          <td> <input type = "text"  name = "name" 
                      size = "30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Street Address: </td>
          <td> <input type = "text"  name = "street"  
                      size = "30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Zip code: </td>
          <td> <input type = "text"  name = "zip"
                      size = "10"  
                      onblur = "getPlace(this.value)" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> City </td>
          <td> <input type = "text"  name = "city"  
                      id = "city"  size = "30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> State </td>
          <td> <input type = "text"  name = "state"  
                      id = "state"  size = "30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
 
      <img src = "popcorn.png"  
           alt = "picture of popcorn" 
           width = "150" height = "150" />
      <p />
       
<!-- The submit and reset buttons -->

      <p>
        <input type = "submit"  value = "Submit Order" />
        <input type = "reset"  value = "Clear Order Form" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
new Ajax.Request("getCityState.php", {
    method: "get",
    parameters: "zip=" + zip,
    onSuccess: function(request) {
        var place = request.responseText.split(', ');
        $("city").value = place[0];
        $("state").value = place[1];
    },
    onFailure: function(request) {
        alert("Error - request failed");
    }
});
```

```html
<?php
// getCityState.php 
//  Gets the form value from the "zip" widget, looks up the 
//  city and state for that zip code, and prints it for the
//  form
      
  $cityState = array("81611" => "Aspen, Colorado",
                     "81411" => "Bedrock, Colorado",
                     "80908" => "Black Forest, Colorado",
                     "80301" => "Boulder, Colorado",
                     "81127" => "Chimney Rock, Colorado",
                     "80901" => "Colorado Springs, Colorado",
                     "81223" => "Cotopaxi, Colorado",
                     "80201" => "Denver, Colorado",                     
                     "81657" => "Vail, Colorado",
                     "80435" => "Keystone, Colorado",
                     "80536" => "Virginia Dale, Colorado"
                     );
  $zip = $_GET["zip"];
  if (array_key_exists($zip, $cityState))
    print $cityState[$zip];
  else
    print " , ";
?>
```

Comment: I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: zip is not defined" error on line popcornA.js:37

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `parameters` needs to be an object like this.

```
parameters : {'zip': zip }
```

Or you can shortcut and put the parameter in the URL string, but lets focus on other problems you are going to run into.

You should probably use observers instead of the `onblur` attribute. It allows you to add as many event handlers to your elements as the browser has memory to handle. It also allows you to separate the javascript from the HTML and organize the observers together.

The `$()` method uses ids and not the names, so you need to add those attributes. This is why you are getting the other error that `zip` is not defined.

so

```
...snip...
<tr>
      <td> Zip code: </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" size="10" />
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td> City </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  name = "city" id="city"
                  id = "city"  size = "30" />
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td> State </td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  name = "state" id="state"  
                  id = "state"  size = "30" />
      </td>
</tr>
...snip...
```

and I would use JSON instead of doing comma splitting as its easier to handle more properties when you need to add them, and less prone to weird splitting errors

```
function getPlace(){

   //getPlace() is an event handler so `this` points to the element being observed

    new Ajax.Request("getCityState.php?zip="+this.getValue(),
        onSuccess: function(request) {
            var place = request.responseJSON;
            $("city").value = place.city;
            $("state").value = place.state;
        },
        onFailure: function(request) {
            alert("Error - request failed");
        }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){
    $('zip').observe('blur',getPlace);
});
```

JSON output requires a little adjustment of your backend script

```
<?php
// getCityState.php 
//  Gets the form value from the "zip" widget, looks up the 
//  city and state for that zip code, and prints it for the
//  form

$cityState = array("81611" => array("city" => "Aspen" ,"state" => "Colorado"),
                 "81411" => array("city" => "Bedrock" ,"state" => ", Colorado"),
                 "80908" => array("city" => "Black Forest","state" => "Colorado"),
                 "80301" => array("city" => "Boulder", "state" => "Colorado"),
                 "81127" => array("city" => "Chimney Rock", "state" => "Colorado"),
                 "80901" => array("city" => "Colorado Springs", "state" => "Colorado"),
                 "81223" => array("city" => "Cotopaxi", "state" => "Colorado"),
                 "80201" => array("city" => "Denver", "state" => "Colorado"),                     
                 "81657" => array("city" => "Vail", "state" => "Colorado"),
                 "80435" => array("city" => "Keystone", "state" => "Colorado"),
                 "80536" => array("city" => "Virginia Dale", "state" => "Colorado")
                 );
header("Content-type: application/json");
//isset() is a faster test than array_key_exists()
if(isset($cityState[$_GET['zip']])
{
    print json_encode($cityState[$_GET['zip']]);
}
else
{
    print "false";
}
```